# Plotly pie graph percentage values overlaying small slices

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph, plotly

I was creating a pie chart via Matplotlib and Plotly from my CSV dataframe. In Plotly, percentage values are expanding out from the pie if slice is so small to percentage value can overlay it. However i couldn't managed to do this expanding feature that Plotly is capable to do.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import date,timedelta,datetime
import plotly.express as px 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches


df = pd.read_csv("US-Border-Crossing/Border_Crossing_Entry_Data.csv",parse_dates=True)
df = df.drop("Port Code",axis=1)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.replace({"Train Passengers":"Train","Rail Containers Full":"Train","Rail Containers Empty":"Train","Trains":"Train","Bus Passengers":"Bus","Buses":"Bus","Trucks":"Truck","Truck Containers Full":"Truck","Truck Containers Empty":"Truck","Personal Vehicles":"Personal\nvehicle","Personal Vehicle Passengers":"Personal\nvehicle\npassengers"})



def pie(by_measure,colors):
       fig, ax = plt.subplots()
       pie = plt.pie(by_measure, labels = by_measure.index,colors=colors, shadow=True, explode=(0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05), autopct="%.2f%%")
       title = plt.title("title")
       title.set_ha("right")
       plt.gca().axis("equal")
       plt.legend(pie[0],by_measure.index, bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5), loc="center right", fontsize=10, bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
       plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.1, right=0.6)
       fig.savefig("matplot.png")
       plt.show()

pie(by_measure,colors)
```

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? At least share a sample of your data.

Comment: I think data is [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/border-crossing-entry-data).  But also, `name 'by_measure' is not defined` and `name 'colors' is not defined`.